# Can a large file stored by my WCF service become corrupted?

Tags: .net, wcf

the thing here is that I have a WCF service to upload files that seems to work fine with small files but with large files it seems to corrupt them or damage them so I cannot open them later.

I want them to be no more than 5MB so I set the binding as I have seen in many posts:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpsBinding"
             maxReceivedMessageSize ="5000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize ="5000000"
             maxBufferSize="5000000"
             transferMode ="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas  maxArrayLength="5000000" maxStringContentLength="5000000" />
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>      
</bindings>
```

The files are being uploaded and stored in a lynux folder shared using samba.
Everything is working fine, files of any type are saved xlsx, png, jpg, pdf, txt, the issue is that when the file's size is greater than (I don't know the exact limit) let's say 1MB I cannot open the files that are saved in the server. I have tested files of hundreds of KB and work but with an excel file of 3MB and a png image of 1.7MB are saved in the server but when I try to open them using the link I provide for the file or directly openning from the folder some message appears. In excel files something about an appdata temporal file not found appears and with the png a message telling "it seems we cannot open this kind of files" appear. I don't know if the correct word is corrupted but can the file somehow damage during the stream or the saving process?

Thanks for your help here.
I don't provide more code since there is no error message during the compilation or while calling the service so I don't have a stacktrace to show specifically where the issue is happening.
The files have the same size as the original? Yes!

Comment: The message size should be bigger imho. Regarding to your problem, I would suggest doing a checksum (md5) of the incomming bytes and checking if it is what you expected.

Comment: Thanks @bradbury9 I think that is a good practice not just a solution for my problem. I will implement this more as a security, but I found the issue, in my buffer (byte array) size It was a fixed 1MB value and that was damaging the file, I changed to a 5MB and worked, to prevent this to happen again I will set a parameter in web.config or get the maxReceivedMessageSize to set this value.

Comment: You can answer your own question, it is even encouraged. If you do so, others with the same problem will find your solution

Answer (score 0):

So if someone runs into the same issue, check your buffer size.
I am using this form of reading the stream:

```
Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(1000000) {}
Dim bytes_read As Integer = 0
Dim bytes_total As Integer = 0
Do
    bytes_read = invoice_stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    bytes_total += bytes_read
Loop While bytes_read > 0
```

I set the web config to 5MB but my buffer size is just 1MB that is why I got corrupted or damaged files when I tried to upload files of a size greater than 1MB.
The confusing part was when the saved files had the same size as the original and that is because of this line that i use to resize the byte array so that I don't get always a 5MB file:

```
Array.Resize(buffer, bytes_total)
```

So basically I stored just the last portion or last 1MB of the stream with a bunch of zeros to complete the original size.